# str is not callable or int is not callable

Tags: python

[Solved] I have made a program in Python using classes, but it is continuously saying `'str' object is not callable`, and if I try commenting lines 7,8 and 16, then it says 
`'int' object is not callable`.

```
class Lambo:
    def __init__(self, color, model_number, average, milage):
        self.color = color
        self.model_number = model_number
        self.average = average
        self.milage = milage
    def color(self):
        print("Lamborghini color is " + self.color)
    def model_number(self):
        print("Lamborghini model number is " + str(self.model_number))
    def average(self):
        print("Lamborghini average is " + str(self.average))
    def milage(self):
        print("Lamborghini milage is " + str(self.milage))
lambor = Lambo("Red", 2016, 20, 8)
lambor.color()
lambor.model_number()
lambor.average()
lambor.milage()
```

Expected Output:

```
Lamborghini color is Red
Lamborghini model_number is 2016
Lamborghini average is 20
Lamborghini milage is 8
```

Also I am using PyCharm community edition 4.5.4

Comment: The problem is that your `__init__` method is *shadowing* the `color` method with the `color` instance attribute. I suggest you use something like `_color` for the instance attributes. The leading underscore is a convention used for private attributes of an object.

Comment: By the way, nothing to do with your problem, but `print` stringifies for you: `print("Lamborghini model number is", self.model_number)`

Comment: @cdarke: only if they are using Python 3 or `from __future__ import print_function`. Take into account that `(...)` around a string works fine for the `print` statement in Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  with respect,  `(...)` with the python 2 `print` statement is just using them for precedence, personally I don't think that's "fine".  For example, even if there is only one value, if you use a trailing comma to suppress the newline then it is printed as a tuple:  `print(5,)` gives: `(5,)`. `print(5),` is necessary.  Is that "fine"?

Comment: @cdarke: sorry, I didn't mean to imply that I was fine with that practice; I very much am not. I'm just pointing out we can't assume the OP is actually using the `print()` function, because nowhere in their code are they using it in a way that'd allow us to be certain about this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  fair enough, that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `color` (etc.) as both the name of a variable (a string) and the name of a method. You can't do that in python.

The error `str is not callable` means that you're putting parentheses after a string variable (hence trying to "call" it like a function). Whenever you see this, there's an error in programming logic.

Answer (score 3):

Your instance has the following attributes:

```
self.color = color
self.model_number = model_number
self.average = average
self.milage = milage
```

Those *mask* the methods you defined; methods are just more attributes, but Python looks at the instance first, and only then at the class to find an attribute:

```
>>> lambor = Lambo("Red", 2016, 20, 8)
>>> lambor.color
'Red'
```

You are not calling the `Lambo.color()` method, you are trying to call the string `'Red'`. Rename either the attributes you set in `__init__`, or rename your methods.

You could use a leading underscore for each name to both remove the clash and to document that the attribute is only used internally in your class:

```
class Lambo:
    def __init__(self, color, model_number, average, milage):
        self._color = color
        self._model_number = model_number
        self._average = average
        self._milage = milage
    def color(self):
        print("Lamborghini color is " + self._color)
    def model_number(self):
        print("Lamborghini model number is " + str(self._model_number))
    def average(self):
        print("Lamborghini average is " + str(self._average))
    def milage(self):
        print("Lamborghini milage is " + str(self._milage))
```

Alternatively, rename the *methods* to state what it is doing; prefix them with `print_`:

```
class Lambo:
    def __init__(self, color, model_number, average, milage):
        self.color = color
        self.model_number = model_number
        self.average = average
        self.milage = milage
    def print_color(self):
        print("Lamborghini color is " + self.color)
    def print_model_number(self):
        print("Lamborghini model number is " + str(self.model_number))
    def print_average(self):
        print("Lamborghini average is " + str(self.average))
    def print_milage(self):
        print("Lamborghini milage is " + str(self.milage))

lambor = Lambo("Red", 2016, 20, 8)
lambor.print_color()
lambor.print_model_number()
lambor.print_average()
lambor.print_milage()
```

Generally speaking, you should not make a class responsible for output like this. You'd normally give a class a `__str__` method that can produce a user-friendly string, then print call `str()` on the instance or directly send it to the `print()` function:

```
class Lambo:
    def __init__(self, color, model_number, average, milage):
        self.color = color
        self.model_number = model_number
        self.average = average
        self.milage = milage
    def __str__(self):
        lines = [
            "Lamborghini color is " + self.color,
            "Lamborghini model number is " + str(self.model_number),
            "Lamborghini average is " + str(self.average),               
            "Lamborghini milage is " + str(self.milage)
        ]
        return '\n'.join(lines)

lambor = Lambo("Red", 2016, 20, 8)
print(lambor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your methods and attributes have the same names.